# What does WcfConfigValidationEnabled do?

Tags: wcf, configuration, csproj

Visual studio injects

```
<WcfConfigValidationEnabled>True</WcfConfigValidationEnabled>
```

into my csproj.

What does this property do, and is there any reason why I would want to disable it?

Comment: FYI, this option is exposed in Visual Studio as _Validate WCF configuration when building the project_ under _WCF Options_ in the project properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe VS is checking the WCF configuration syntax as part of the build process. It will then be able to alert you to any configuration errors before you run the code.

You can disable it if you want, but then if configuration errors occur during development, they will be only be seen at runtime.

Its more a design time convenience, than a runtime convenience.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "the WCF configuration syntax". Do you mean the relevant sections of the app.config/web.config file?

Comment: Correct. Its parsing the configuration file for validity.